# Free functions and unit-testing

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost, tdd, visitor-pattern

I'm interested in testing the function navigateFoo below:

```
virtual void navigateFoo(const vector<Node>& nodes) 
{
    // find the foo node in the list of nodes
    Nodes::const_iterator fooNodeI = findFooNode(nodes);

    // if we have found the foo node
    if(fooNodeI!=nodes.end()) 
    {
        // the id for retrieving the associated Foo Container from the cache 
        std::string id = getCacheIdentifier(*fooNodeI);
        // the Foo Container associated with the Foo Node
        FooContainer& container = _fooContainerCache->get(id);

        // the name of the Foo item within the Foo Container
        std::string name = getName(*fooNodeI);
        // if foo is not found in the associated container, add it
        if(findFoo(name, container)==container.end()) 
        {
            container.push_back( createFoo(getData(*fooNodeI)) );
        }
    }
}
```

Node is of type boost::variant, where this variant contains the types Foo1, Foo2, Bar1 and Bar2 etc.

The free function `findFooNode` uses the visitor pattern to locate the Foo Node (of type Foo1 or Foo2)

The free function `getCacheIdentifier` also uses the visitor pattern to locate the cache identifier for the Foo Node.

`_fooContainerCache` is a dependency injection and is mocked in my unit-test.

getName is again a free function, as is `createFoo`.

All the free functions are themselves unit-tested and are used in other functions in my code.

Things are easily tested up to the line:

```
FooContainer& container = _fooContainerCache->get(id);
```

as I only need to check with the mock that the expected id is presented to the get function.

However, to test the code after this line, I need to check the changes made to the FooContainer returned by reference from my mock. However, if createFoo were to change in the future, which I know it will, this results in me have to change my unit tests for both createFoo and the navigateFoo. However, if I was to dependency inject a FooFactory instead, I would avoid this problem, doing this instead:

```
container.push_back( _fooFactory->create( getData(*fooNodeI) ));
```

Then I can mock this function also in my unit-test. If the behaviour behind this interface changes, then it wont result in me have to rewrite tests for navigateFoo.

However, when I wrote createFoo I never felt it natural that it should be implemented as an interface, so now I feel that I'm adding an interface simply to be able to write better tests. And then the question arises, should I have interface for any other of my free functions? Are there any rules of thumb in this regard?

Comment: It seems like you are testing at too small a level. Testing with a mock like this gives little value because changing the code at all will break the test, even though there may be no observable change to clients.

Comment: @Billy ONeal Do you mean that if you were testing the line of code above with the push_back that you would simply check that the FooContainer object is increased in size by one and leave it at that?

Comment: @Baz (if possible) I would also somehow check it's content, not only the container's size.

Comment: @Billy ONeal What if I pass *(fooNodeI+1) by mistake to getData?

Comment: @Baz: I would test all the observable behavior of `navigateFoo`. If someone makes a mistake then that behavior should be observable in that `navigateFoo` would give wrong answers.

Comment: @BЈовић I would also fell most comfortable doing that but since I know the behaviour of create is going to change I feel it more sensible just now to have an interface instead of the free function. I can also then ask its mock if the expected argument is passed to it.

Comment: @Billy ONeal Exactly and since the behaviour of the create function is leaking out here, I will have to repeat the tests I've already written for create. This is why I'm inclined to use an interface here instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And then the question arises, should I have interface for any other of my free functions?

It is essential for [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) that every class should have an interface. I personally do not follow that rule 100%.

> Are there any rules of thumb in this regard?

Follow your intuition. If you feel that you need that a class needs an interface to simplify unit testing, then just add an interface. It will simplify your and maintainer's lives.

However, watch out for [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it).

---

Also, [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/150045/20065) might clear some of doubts.

Comment: That would lead to a lot of dependency injection to the class in which navigateFoo is defined, as I don't think any of these free functions would belong to the same interface. Does this mean that navigateFoo is badly designed in your opinion and that it should be broken up into smaller parts?

Comment: ISP is not "every class has an interface." It means "have a large number of small interfaces rather than a few large ones." It is essentially SRP for interfaces.

Comment: @BЈовић Furthermore, std algorithms are often free functions and they don't have interfaces.

Comment: @Baz That is true, but they are not going to change. What you want to mock is not std functions, but you want to break your classes.